# Postgres/Knex How to get all entries where two timestamps contain a specified time period between them

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timestamp, knex.js, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm building an application using a Postgres database, which involves comparing schedules. I'm using knex to connect it up to node; but if the solution is best served by a raw query, I can go that route as well.

I have a table called `"Schedules"` which contains a `"from_time"` and a `"to_time"`.

I want to be able to give the db a `"start_time"` and `"end_time"` and find:

1. all schedules that can contain `"start_time"` and "end_time" (i.e., `from_time <= start_time && end_time >= to_time`)
2. All schedules that overlap the `"start_time"` and `"end_time"` (i.e., 
   `(start_time <= from_time && end_time > from_time) || (start_time < to_time && end_time >= from_time))`

One possible solution I considered is simply storing the values as integers in the Unix epoch... which is my backup plan.  However, since these really are time values, it's probably best to keep them in timestamp value format.

Comment: Do `from_time` and `to_time` represent *timestamps* or *times*? If they do represent times, does it make sense to cross the 00:00 time? (i.e.: schedule starts at 22:00, and ends at 02:00 next day).

Comment: When you get the results: Do you need to distinguish between `overlaps` and `is contained in` (which is just a special case for `overlaps`)?

Comment: Take a look at http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fbf5fe4c8b5611d92f87a7766f53cc4b, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the question? I don't quite understand what do you want to find here.

Answer (score -1):

This one is for your first condition

```
knex.select('*').from('Schedules').where('from_time', '<=', start_time).where('to_time', '<=', end_time)
```

This one is for your second

```
knex.select('*').from('Schedules').where(function () {
    this.where('from_time', '>=', start_time).where('from_time' ,'<', end_time))
}).orWhere(function () {
    this.where('to_time', '>', start_time).where('from_time' ,'<=', end_time))
})
```